# winter's method result accuracy in R

Tags: r

I have the following data

```r
yt = c(3.234, 3.656, 3.895, 5.348, 7.751, 8.494, 7.270, 5.210, 4.218, 4.259, 4.209, 4.946,
       3.845, 4.433, 4.554, 6.161, 9.356, 9.516, 7.750, 5.474, 4.915, 4.687, 5.035, 5.766,
       4.731, 5.267, 5.672, 7.479, 9.958, 10.852, 9.155, 6.673, 5.374, 5.191, 5.231, 6.068,
       4.984, 6.073, 6.511, 8.209, 11.384, 12.604, 9.627, 8.033, 7.577, 5.532, 5.526, 6.535,
       5.418, 5.830, 7.962, 9.996, 14.235, 14.993, 12.137, 9.278, 7.289, 6.838, 7.058, 6.888,
       5.609, 7.056, 8.616, 11.353, 14.565, 14.924, 13.180, 10.547, 9.318, 8.173, 8.951, 9.533,
       7.149, 8.550, 9.436, 12.796, 17.202, 18.356, 15.994)

yt = ts(data = yt,start = 2012,end = 2018,frequency = 12)
```

and my goal is to do an analysis (accuracy) with a forecast of it (the same as what minitab does).
In minitab
[image]

the accuracy result is

[image: accuracy Minitab]

Now if I apply the `forecast` library in R.

```r
library(forecast)
winter = HoltWinters(x = yt,alpha = 0.2,beta = 0.2,gamma = 0.2,seasonal = "additive")
# or forecast
winterf = hw(y = yt, seasonal = "additive",alpha = 0.2,beta = 0.2,gamma = 0.2)

# ----- applied accuracy for winterf-----

accuracy(winterf) # generate error
[1] "Model: ETS(A,A,A)"
Error in ets(x, "AAA", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, gamma = gamma, phi = phi,  : 
  No model able to be fitted


# ----- applied accuracy for winter-----
accuracy(winter)
Error in accuracy.default(holt5) : 
  First argument should be a forecast object or a time series.
```

well on the one hand I understand that R chooses the best value for alpha, beta and gamma. But I want to add it manually.

**Is there a way to fix this error? Am I doing something wrong?**

> Note: In minitab I just enter the values and it automatically generates the accuracy table

Answer (score 1):

The `winter` object needs to go through `forecast` before calling `accuracy`.

```
f1 <- forecast(winter)
accuracy(f1)
#>                       ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE    MAPE      MASE
#> Training set 0.007231816 0.9710458 0.7445564 -1.909893 9.60479 0.7316624
#> ACF1
#> Training set 0.6804071
```

Comment: interesting, is there any way that minitab's MAPE (9.80159) equals the result of R (9.60479)?